# npm module Imager installation

Tags: node.js, npm, graphicsmagick

I have been trying to install npm package because for some odd reason the module and GraphicsMagick library vanished into thin air from my machine(but that is a discussion for some other day).

Now I have installed the library but when I run

> sudo npm install --save imager

I get a long list of errors. starting from

> Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/imager/node_modules/pkgcloud/node_modules/request/node_modules/json-stringify-safe/LICENSE'

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Many npm modules are skins over previously written native code projects.
In this case : GraphicsMagick

If you first do the install of GraphicsMagick (outside of node/npm) or whichever is the underlying project.  Get it up and running and only then do the npm install of its skin it will work.  I just did these steps on ubuntu for npm module imager and the install worked fine.

Understand the meaning of npm install with a -g flag (global) - If the module makes available a command line executable then do npm install -g xxxx